# Blending capitalisation and abbreviation

Tags: capitalization, acronyms

Is there a term that describes the process of capitalising words to identify them with an acronym?

For example when writing about MS (multiple sclerosis), text can be something like "my Micro Stories" or "the works of art were Mostly Striking".

Thanks

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking.  Why, when writing about multiple sclerosis would I capitalize Micro Stories??  Are you making a sort of pun?

Answer (score 1):

You could say those particular words are written in **title case** to indicate it’s an acronym.

> **Title case (capital case, headline style)**
>   "*The Quick Brown Fox Jumps over the Lazy Dog*"
>   A mixed-case style with all words capitalised, except for certain subsets (particularly articles and short prepositions and conjunctions) defined by rules that are not universally standardised. The standardisation is only at the level of house styles and individual style manuals.
>   - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case

However, I’d prefer to write the phrase in long form the first time it was used, followed by its acronym in brackets, and then use the acronym from there on in the document.